# Nextjs v.10 getstaticprops "revalidate" stop working on docker container

Tags: docker, next.js, containers, vultr

first of all i am not an expert with docker deployment.

The problem i have is that the revalidate feature suddenly stopped working and only work again only if i restart the docker container. For ex. The stock on one of the product did not change.

The webapp built using nextjs v.10 it is e-com webapp and the data came from other webapp which is wordpress that primarily served as data only.

In short, nextjs as frontend deployed on docker container on vultr vps AND wordpress as backend. Revalidate feature work for around 1 month and i need to reproduce or restart the docker container to make revalidate feature work again.

I am not really sure if this problem relate to nextjs or vultr or docker.
Could someone suggest a solution or anything? I am really appreciate it if someone can help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please share code blocks or use case? Like revalidate cached time or some error logs.

Answer (score 0):

Static Regeneration (revalidate flag for getStaticProps) need to run NextJs server. As you said in your case it alredy configured and runs for a month. So I think it causes by some error in your nextjs server and it stopped running. Please check the nextjs server logs.

Comment: The code is just typical nextjs where we do fetching data and set revalidate time. Website working fine for a few weeks, and yes the 2nd time refresh of browser fetched updated data. So i assume nextjs server got an error when updating the cache? Because the getstaticprops is common fetching i thought i don't need to write error log. But if i do need error log, what should i check for?(btw thanks for answering my question)

Answer (score 0):

Some code would be helpful, and also logs if there is anything there.

You could start debugging this by adding logging into the start of the `getStaticProps`. If the log message appears, the invalidate works and gets triggered, but it might fail later on before actually updating the cache.

Please also note that after the reinvalidate timeout the first page request will be the old one, so you would need to refresh the page twice to see the updated information. Also if the `getStaticProps` fails, the old cached page will be used.

> When a request is made to a page that was pre-rendered at build time, it will initially show the cached page.
>
> Any requests to the page after the initial request and before 10 seconds are also cached and instantaneous.
>
> After the 10-second window, the next request will still show the cached (stale) page
>
> Next.js triggers a regeneration of the page in the background.
>
> Once the page has been successfully generated, Next.js will invalidate the cache and show the updated product page. If the background regeneration fails, the old page remains unaltered.

Source: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#incremental-static-regeneration

Comment: The code is just typical nextjs where we do fetching data and set revalidate time. Website working fine for a few weeks, and yes the 2nd time refresh of browser fetched updated data. So i assume nextjs server got an error when updating the cache? Because the getstaticprops is common fetching i thought i don't need to write error log. But if i do need error log, what should i check for? (Btw thanks for answering my question)

Comment: If it works on 2nd refresh, then it's working as it is supposed to. The first time someone comes in, they are served the old data, and on the background it refreshes the cache and the 2nd one coming in gets the new data. This is so that the 1st user gets the response faster.